# Jpa OneToMany with condition

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0, spring-data-jpa

I have 2 tables:

The first is "Persons":

- person_id,
- person_name

The second is "PersonsGraphs":

- person_id1,
- person_id2,
- relation_type

I'm looking for a way to build a "family tree".

**My first option is**: load personGraphs into a HashTable and then recursively build the tree.

**The second option I have come up with**: use `@OneToMany  jpa-relation`. This can work, but sometimes I have some `relation_types` that I want/don't want to include. Are there any options that would allow me to set some condition on the `@OneToMany` relation while using `@JoinTable`?

Thanks!
Oak

Comment: Side note : I think one table should be named as Person & other as PersonGraph.

Comment: agree with on that :)

Answer (score 7):

Try to use Hibernate `@Where` [annotation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#mapping-column-where), for example:

```
@Entity
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Gender gender;

    @ManyToOne
    private Person parent;

    @Where(clause = "gender = 'MALE'")
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "person")
    private List<Person> sons;

    @Where(clause = "gender = 'FEMALE'")
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "person")
    private List<Person> daughters;
}

public enum Gender {
   MALE, FEMALE
}
```

Comment: Is there an equivalent for this for JPA standard?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend creating a Relationship class to model the join table.

Person - OneToMany - relations - Relationship - ManyToOne source - ManyToOne target

In EclipseLink you can add an Expression criteria to any relationship mapping,

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/MappingSelectionCriteria

Comment: Hey @James, Is it possible to achieve the same result without EclipseLink?